# How to insert title in mdframed?

Tags: mdframed

How to insert title in mdframed?
In my example does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\section{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[numbers=left,frame=single,framesep=5mm,label=Title]
text

text

text

text

text

text

text
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

I need

------------title------------
[image]

And here tytle vertical position?

Comment: I think `\mdfsetup{frametitlealignment=\center}` might help. `:)`

Comment: You are using some keys which don't belong to `mdframed` (`numbers`, `frame`, `framesep`); those are keys for `lstlistings` from the `listings` package and not for `mdframed`.

Comment: See for example file *mdframed-example-default.pdf* -> example 6

Comment: good question, indeed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your example code you are using some keys which don't belong to `mdframed`; `numbers`, `frame`, `framesep` are keys for `lstlistings` from the `listings` package and not for `mdframed`; with mdframed, you need `frametitle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{frametitlealignment=\center}

\begin{document}

\section{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={The title of the frame}]
text
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the edit to the original question, here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {\mdfsetup{
    frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space#1\space}},
    innertopmargin=10pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\center
    }
  \begin{mdframed}%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{The frame title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answers is perfect, but and the vertical position, with figure above?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva I updated my answer with a new example code. Is it something like that what you need?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: You become a mdframed master ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Nah, I'm still just an apprentice; you are *the* master ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This, saved my slide today!