# A fancy box for non-verb text, but like that of Fancyvrb

Tags: captions, boxes

How can I create, without a verbatim environment, these nice boxes that the `Fancyvrb` package produces:

[image: Image from Fancyvrb]

The sibling package `Fancybox` (by the same author) doesn't allow for the caption being placed onto the box's sides.

Comment: I'd have a look at the package `mdframed`

Comment: Wow! That's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: When you have a working solution, you can add a self-answer here.

Comment: The second code in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69154/3954  could be used as a starting point.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina What does the `-\ht\strutbox` parameter mean?

Comment: @NVaughan a `\strutbox` is an `\hbox` containing rule with `0` width whose height and depth add up to the `\normalbaselineskip` in use; `\ht\strutbox` is the height of the `\strutbox`; setting `frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox` raises the title by an amount equal to the height of the `\strutbox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using @GonzaloMedina's code ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69154/3954)), and @egreg's suggestion, the desired code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {\mdfsetup{
    frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space#1\space}},
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\center
    }
  \begin{mdframed}%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{The frame title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

It produces the following PDF (cropped here):

[image: mdframed example]