# How to insert title in innerrightmargin using mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I have tried to insert title in `innerrightmargin` using `mdframed` and found [How to insert title in mdframed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69148/how-to-insert-title-in-mdframed) this example. But this is only for top of the frame. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
{\mdfsetup{
 frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space#1\space}},
 innertopmargin=10pt,
 topline=false,
 leftline=false,
 frametitleaboveskip=-\ht\strutbox,
 frametitlealignment=\center
}
\begin{mdframed}%
 }
 {\end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}{The frame title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Example:

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Your question is not completely clear, at least for me. Where exactly do you want the title to appear?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Inside frame with vertical right alignment (like end of every line (Morbi, ul-, ligula, hendrerit etc..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update after the edit to the question

Two options; in the first one, a vertical strip is used for the title and the vertical strip's length will vary according to the title's length ; in the second option, the vertical strip will be as long as the frame's height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{greentitle}{RGB}{165,224,168}

\newenvironment{myenvi}[1]
  {\begin{mdframed}[
   bottomline=false,
   leftline=false,
   linecolor=greentitle,
   innerrightmargin=25pt,
   singleextra={
     \node[overlay,anchor=south east,fill=greentitle,rotate=90,font=\color{white}\scshape] at (P) {#1};
    },
   firstextra={
     \node[overlay,anchor=south east,fill=greentitle,rotate=90,font=\color{white}\scshape] at (P) {#1};
    },
  ]
 }
 {\end{mdframed}}

\newenvironment{myenvii}[1]
  {\begin{mdframed}[
   bottomline=false,
   leftline=false,
   linecolor=greentitle,
   innerrightmargin=25pt,
   singleextra={
     \fill[greentitle] (P) rectangle ([xshift=-15pt]P|-O);
     \node[overlay,anchor=south east,rotate=90,font=\color{white}\scshape] at (P) {#1};
    },
   firstextra={
     \fill[greentitle] (P) rectangle ([xshift=-15pt]P|-O);
     \node[overlay,anchor=south east,rotate=90,font=\color{white}\scshape] at (P) {#1};
    },
  ]
 }
 {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvi}{the frame title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myenvi}

\begin{myenvii}{the frame title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myenvii}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Initial version

Like this?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\vvv#1{\leavevmode\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\xvvv#1\relax}

\def\xvvv{\afterassignment\xxvvv\let\tmp= }

\def\xxvvv{%
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\egroup\ \vbox\bgroup\let\next\xvvv
\else\ifx\tmp\relax\egroup\egroup\let\next\relax
\else
%\hbox{\tmp}%original
\hbox to 1.1em{\hfill\tmp\hfill}% centred
\let\next\xvvv\fi\fi
\next}

\makeatother

\newenvironment{myenv}[1]
  {\begin{mdframed}[
   topline=false,
   leftline=false,
   innerrightmargin=40pt,
   singleextra={
     \node[overlay,anchor=north east] at (P) {\vvv{#1}};
    },
   firstextra={
     \node[overlay,anchor=north east] at (P) {\vvv{#1}};
    },
  ]
 }
 {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{The~frame title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I used [`David Carlisle's answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122471/3954) to [Vertical text (not in table)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122466/3954) to write the title vertically.

Comment: title should be place in right rule before but the styles are same `\raggedleft`.

Comment: @Balaji I don't understand. Please describe in more detail the desired positioning.

Comment: @Balaji Ah, seeing your edit now I think I know what you want. In some minutes (if none else has provided an answer) I'll give you a possibility.

Comment: I have updated my questions.

Comment: @Balaji Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Great, now it's working fine as per my required.

Comment: @Balaji I fixed some problems with the original code; the improved version is now better. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: How do increase `rightline` rule as per attached screenshot?

Comment: @Balaji Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer and i hope this is very helpful to another users also.